# User object is sometimes nil in Clearance SessionsController after successful sign in

Tags: ruby, clearance

I've assumed that if `status.success?` is `true` then I could rely on `@user` being present. But *sometimes* I get an error that `@user` is `nil`.

How is it possible that the reference to `@user` within `#track_sign_in` would sometimes be `nil`?

```
class Clearance::SessionsController < Clearance::BaseController
  before_action :redirect_signed_in_users, only: [:new]
  skip_before_action :require_login, only: [:create, :new, :destroy], raise: false

  def create
    @user = authenticate(params)

    sign_in(@user) do |status|
      if status.success?
        track_sign_in
        redirect_back_or url_after_create
      else
        flash.now.alert = status.failure_message
        render template: "sessions/new", status: :unauthorized
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def track_sign_in
    @user.update!(sign_in_count: @user.sign_in_count + 1)
  end
end
```

I used to get this error even *before* changing the above controller logic to include 2FA. Here's the full controller now. I've been getting the error more often recently since changing it, but I've seen the error when the controller looked like the above too.

```
class SessionsController < Clearance::SessionsController
  before_action :skip_authorization
  layout 'simple'

  def create
    @user = find_user

    authed_user = authenticate(params)

    if params[:session][:otp_attempt].present? && session[:otp_user_id]
      authenticate_user_with_otp_two_factor(@user)
    elsif !@user || !@user.two_factor_required? || !authed_user || (@user.two_factor_required? && !@user.two_factor_setup?)
      do_sign_in(authed_user)
    else
      prompt_for_otp_two_factor(authed_user)
    end
  end

  private

  def valid_otp_attempt?(user)
    user.authenticate_otp(params[:session][:otp_attempt])
  end

  def authenticate_user_with_otp_two_factor(user)
    if valid_otp_attempt?(user)
      # Remove any lingering user data from login
      session.delete(:otp_user_id)

      do_sign_in(user)
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = 'Invalid code. Try again.'
      prompt_for_otp_two_factor(user, :unauthorized)
    end
  end

  def prompt_for_otp_two_factor(user, status = :ok)
    @user = user

    session[:otp_user_id] = user.id
    render 'sessions/two_factor', status: status
  end

  def do_sign_in(user)
    sign_in(user) do |status|
      if status.success?
        track_sign_in
        redirect_back_or url_after_create
      else
        flash.now.alert = status.failure_message
        render template: "sessions/new", status: :unauthorized
      end
    end
  end

  def find_user
    if session[:otp_user_id]
      User.find(session[:otp_user_id])
    elsif params[:session][:email]
      User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email])
    end
  end

  def track_sign_in
    @user.update!(
      sign_in_count: @user.sign_in_count + 1,
      last_sign_in_at: Time.current,
      last_sign_in_ip: request.remote_ip,
    )
  end
end
```

And here's a screen shot of the stack track:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that's where the stack trace points to? And that there's no other code you've omitted from your question, which might possibly unset `@user`? I agree this looks impossible, given the information you've provided above, unless there's something critical missing from the description. Or unless the `sign_in`/`status.success?` methods are doing something extremely weird.

Comment: @TomLord I'm pretty sure! I've added a screen shot of the stack trace and the full controller. I've been getting the error all along, even before changing to add 2FA. I added a check for user now to prevent the error, but I've always been baffled as to how `@user` being `nil` was even possible. I thought maybe there might be something I was overlooking.

Comment: @TomLord Also, I realize that in some cases `@user` is being passed around and other cases not. I grabbed some of this logic from a 2FA tutorial, got everything working and didn't want to touch it until I have time to go through and refactor. But I'm assuming it really shouldn't matter.

Comment: Oh... Well now, that complete code looks quite different. This makes a lot more sense.

Comment: What happens if `find_user` returns `nil` (but `authenticate(params)`  returns a valid `user` record)? Then on line 6 we set `@user = nil`, and on line  12 we fall into the conditional because `elsif !@user ...` returns `true`. So in `sign_in(user)` the `user` variable is set as expected, **but `@user == nil`**. Your confusion stems from passing around two different values: `user` and `@user`.

Comment: @TomLord Wow, great catch! I'll be writing a test case for that scenario. The error was happening even before I introduced all the 2FA logic though; I've been baffled by this for a while. It's clear I introduced a new issue. I'll clean up the controller and report back.